# How to use simple output parameters?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I'm new to Oracle, so I apologize for such a simple question, but I've already wasted several hours on it.

I have the following stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure MyTestProc (outparam OUT VARCHAR2) AS
begin
   select 'test' into outparam from dual;
end;
```

How do I call this stored procedure, and insert the value of `outparam`  into a variable? I'd like to be able to do this so I can then use the result for other things, e.g., printing it to output.

Using functions, I was able to do this as easy as:

```
variable tmpString VARCHAR2(100);
call MyTestFunc('test') INTO :tmpString;
print tmpString;
```

How do I do this with stored procedures?

Comment: Are you calling this procedure from code?

Comment: I've tried  Lots of things.  I felt that posting what I've tried would only bring this question deeper into oblivion--it should be simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are still using SQL*Plus variables

```
variable tmpString VARCHAR2(100);
begin
  myTestProc( :tmpString );
end;
/
print tmpString;
```

If you want to do it in PL/SQL

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  tmpString VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  myTestProc( tmpString );
  dbms_output.put_line( tmpString );
END;
```